# Autoboxing wth ++,-- operator in java

Tags: java, autoboxing

I am confuse about autoboxing unboxing in java. Please see my following two progarm.

```
Integer x = 400;
Integer y = x;
x++; x--;
System.out.println((x==y));

The output is false. 
I known why the output is false. Because of autoboxing x.
```

---

```
Integer x = 100;
Integer y = x;
x++; x--;
System.out.println((x==y));

The output is true.
But the program is same as the upper. Why the output is true? 
Please explain me detail.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: @TBZ: Use @<name> when addressing someone in a comment, this will give them a notice.

Comment: @Keppil Just an FYI, the notification system now pings you regardless :)

Comment: @Brian: What does `regardless` mean? Do you have a link describing when you need to use @<name> and when you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Integers -128 to 127 are cached, so in second example x and y refer to the same Integer instance.

```
Integer x = 100;          // x refers to cached 100
x++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int var = x.intValue();
var++;
x = Integer.valueOf(var);  // returns cached 100
```

See Integer.valueOf(int) API.

Comment: +1, but *may* be cached (but almost always are)

Comment: I think Jon Skeet's answer to the Q this is a Dup of is far more comprehensive, especially in that regard.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev: Thank you very much +1 :). What is the same Integer instance?

Comment: @T8Z added more details